# Extracting String in Parenthesis - SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have the following strings in a column called Qualifications:

```
D.Ther (ZIMB) 2017
D.Ther (ZIMB) 2016
Cert in Dental Therapy (ZIMB) 2017
D Tech (ZIMB) 1971
D Tech (The South African Dental Technicians Council -S.A) 1984
D Tech (ZIMB) 1987
Dental Technology (Natal-S.A) 1991
```

How do i retain the string in parentheses only using SSIS? for example `ZIMB`, `Natal-S.A`

Comment: Use a combination of `substring` and `findstring` in a `derived column` transformation.

Comment: Many thanks, i am a novice in this area, please supply me with function if you do not mind.

Comment: I tried the following and its not working: SUBSTRING([Primary Qualifications]+"(",2,FINDSTRING(")",[Primary Qualifications],2) - 1)

Comment: *its not working* -- Not working *how*?  *please supply me with function if you do not mind*  -- This is not a code writing service

Comment: thanks here with SUBSTRING([Primary Qualifications],FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],"(",1) + 1,FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],")",2) - FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],"(",1) + 1)

Comment: @user5684073 - you probably got negative feedback for not showing what you tried. Put that comment into your question to avoid this. Plus, you should select an answer below to make people stop showing up to answer this question. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this by identifying the location of the opening and closing parenthesis [FINDSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017). Knowing those two values, you can then use the [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/substring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017) operation to extract the middle text.

Debugging is challenging with SSIS expressions. I would take the following approach. Add 3, yes 3, Derived Column Tasks to your data flow.

### Derived Column 1

Add a new column called `OpeningParenthesis` of type DT_I4 (32 bit integer). The following expression will populate the value

```
FINDSTRING([Qualifications], "(", 1)
```

Find the first opening parenthesis in the column (case sensitive) Qualifications, starting at position 1.

### Derived Column 2

Add a new called `ClosingParenthesis` of type DT_I4. The following expression will be used

```
FINDSTRING([Qualifications], ")", [OpeningParenthesis])
```

Find the first opening parenthesis in the column (case sensitive) Qualifications, starting at the location of the opening parenthesis.

### Derived Column 3

Here we'll use a substring operation to slice out the middle text. Add a new column named `Country` and the type will be DT_WSTR.  Use an expression like

```
SUBSTRING([Qualifications], [OpeningParenthesis], [ClosingParenthesis]-[OpeningParenthesis])
```

You might need to have a plus or minus 1 in that length calculation `[ClosingParenthesis]-[OpeningParenthesis]`

I don't have SSIS open at the moment so that's the approximate answer. Any of the positions from FINDSTR might be off by one but using this approach allows you to attach the Data Viewer between components to determine where things have gone wrong.

Also, depending on your data there might be issues if the column doesn't contain parenthesis or if it's null.

Comment: Once again, you provide a much more detailed answer, but ultimately the same (even the untested nature of it!)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but should get you close.

substring -- parses a string with start point and how many chars

findstring will locate the position of the first value of the string searched.

```
substring([column], findstring([column],"(")+1,findstring([column],")") - findstring([column],"(")+1)
```

Comment: Many thanks, i get an error message which says the function findstring requires 3 parameters not 2

Comment: I thought the last parameter was unnecessary and assumed ,1. Just add ,1 to each findstring. I have too many languages to keep up with!

Comment: Many thanks all, the following function is close to what i am looking for: SUBSTRING([Primary Qualifications],FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],"(",1) + 1,FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],")",1) - FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],"(",1) + 1) This works well except for one closing bracket which is remaining i.e. Chicago -USA) 
Karachi-INDIA) 
Louisville-USA)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the right way as below:
SUBSTRING([Primary Qualifications],FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],"(",1) + 1,FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],")",1) - FINDSTRING([Primary Qualifications],"(",1) - 1)